# K-Means equality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, clustering, centroid

Is there any geometrical and or short proof for the equality

> ${\displaystyle {\underset { }{ }}\sum _{i=1}^{k}\sum _{\mathbf {x}
> \in S_{i}}\left\|\mathbf {x} -{\boldsymbol {\mu}}_{i}\right\|^{2}}={\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{k}\,{\frac
> {1}{2|S_{i}|}}\,\sum _{\mathbf {x} ,\mathbf {y} \in
> S_{i}}\left\|\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {y} \right\|^{2}}   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   (*)$

One way to prove this is to take into consideration the equality

> ${\displaystyle \sum _{\mathbf {x} \in S_{i}}\left\|\mathbf {x}
> -{\boldsymbol {\mu }}_{i}\right\|^{2}=\sum _{\mathbf {x} \neq \mathbf {y} \in S_{i}}(\mathbf {x} -{\boldsymbol {\mu }}_{i})({\boldsymbol {\mu }}_{i}-\mathbf {y} )}$

where I cannot find any geometrical meaning.

Could someone help me to prove (*) in a geometrical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an identity that holds for each cluster $S_i$ separately. Thus let $S$ be a set of $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mu = \frac{1}{m} \sum_i x_i$ be their mean. Then since $\sum_i x_i = m \mu$
$$
\sum_i \|x_i - \mu\|^2 = \sum_i \left( \|x_i\|^2  - 2 x_i^T \mu + \|\mu\|^2\right)
= \sum_i \|x_i\|^2 - 2 |S| \|\mu\|^2 + |S| \|\mu\|^2 
$$
which equals $\sum_i \|x_i\|^2 - |S|\|\mu\|^2$.
On the other hand
$$
\sum_{i,j} \|x_i - x_j \|^2 = \sum_{i,j} \left(\|x_i\|^2 + \|x_j\|^2 - 2 x_i^Tx_j \right) = 2 |S|\sum_i \|x\|^2 - 2 |S|^2 \|\mu\|^2
$$ 
and the identity follows. There is no obvious geometric interpretation that I can think of.